# Error accessing Schema from web app over over local network

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows-authentication

I have a web app that is working correctly on the computer running the server, but when I attempt to run the web app on another device over the local network I get this error:

> The specified schema name "WORKGROUP\LAPTOP-1" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

The command I'm trying to execute is the following:

```
protected void Home_pt()
{
    string nametime;
    string name;
    string time;
    string tname = null;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Public\\public website\\slDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;");

    if (thiddenfield.Value == String.Empty)
    {
        Show("error: empty tname");
    }
    else
    {
        tname = thiddenfield.Value;
    }

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM trecordTable WHERE name='" + tname + "'", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<string> namedatelist = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                name = reader["name"].ToString();
                time = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                namedatelist.Add(name + time);
            }
            nametime = Regex.Replace(namedatelist[0].ToString(), "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
            Session["nametime"] = nametime;
            hftstate.Value = nametime;
        }
    }
}

protected void Fill_t(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nametime = Session["nametime"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Public\\public website\\slDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;");

    conn.Open();

    using (var cmdtx1 = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('" + nametime + "') IS NULL CREATE TABLE " + nametime + "([Id]    INT   IDENTITY NOT NULL,  [item]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  [CtrlType] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  [six] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  [seven]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  [eight]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL); IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT item FROM " + nametime + ") INSERT INTO " + nametime + " (item,CtrlType,hflabel) VALUES ('At','atscroll','cstat')", conn))
    {
        cmdtx1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Are there permissions I should edit in SSMS?

Also, I recognize it's vulnerable to injection, but I would like to fix this first.

Comment: What's the value of `nametime`?

Comment: It is procedurally generated based on user input. Basically an entered name and then the current time.

Comment: I didn't ask how it is created. I asked what it's value is. Your problem is there.

Comment: Added additional code to show where it comes from. An example value would be: "Pete01272017"

Comment: So you think it is the nametime variable causing the problem even though the command works fine when it's run on the same machine as the server?

Comment: The source code just shows you connecting to your own computer (`localhost`), mounting a file on your own hard drive (`C:\...`), If you run that same code on another computer, it will go to the SQLEXPRESS instance on that computer and mount the file from its own hard drive. If you change the code to make it able to "run the web app on another device over the local network", please show which changes you make.

Comment: Overall, it is unclear what exactly changes when you say "on another device over the local network". Do you run the above code in a server, and it works when you send requests to it locally but not from another computer? Do you copy the program over to another computer? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry yea I could explain it better. 
The condition that works is running SSMS and the web server on the server computer (computer 1), and then opening a browser and visiting the web app and executing the command. 
The condition that isn't working is then using another computer (computer 2) to access the web app hosted on (computer 1). Computer 2 accesses the web app via local IP. The web app sends a command to the server to execute the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow so the post put up for about 30 seconds (and then deleted?) by Ubercoder worked!

"I suspect that nametime is not being set to include the required schema - normally this is [dbo]

This should work"

```
using (var cmdtx1 = new SqlCommand(
 "IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo]." + nametime + @"') IS NULL 
    CREATE TABLE [dbo]." + nametime +  @"
     ([Id] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,  
      [item]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  
      [CtrlType] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  
      [six] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  
      [seven]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  
      [eight]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL
     ); 


 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT item FROM [dbo]." + nametime + @") 
  INSERT INTO [dbo]." + nametime + @"
      (item,CtrlType,hflabel) 
  VALUES ('At','atscroll','cstat')",
 conn))
{
cmdtx1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Ubercoder if you repost your answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: It is good coding practice to specify schema.   Aaron Bertrand has a very good post on this. https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True` in the connection string, which user connects to the database and which default schema is used depends on the Windows environment.

Your IIS might be setup to use a different Windows user credential for remote connections than for local connections. Or when you also have integrated Windows authentication enabled in IIS for your application, then the logged on Windows User on the client computer is used to authenticate against the database.

So either do not use integrated security or make sure that all users who want to be able to connect have access to the schema dbo and use it as their default schema.

See [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4036/default-schema-for-windows-group-in-sql-server/) on how to set a default schema for a Windows Network Group.

---

Warning: Personal opinion

Specifying the schema name in the SQL statement as proposed by Ubercoder would work as well, but this is generally not a good idea because this makes it much more difficult to migrate the application to an SQL server where it is meant to share the database with a different application or when you want to implement a multi-tenant-scenario.

It's also very easy for a developer to forget adding the schema prefix in an sql statement. And this error will then not be spotted so easily during development when the developer uses a login where dbo is the default schema.

Comment: Is it ok to not use integrated security? What sort of vulnerabilities does that create?

Comment: What type of authentication to use depends a lot on your application scenario. Configuring the default schema for Windows users is certainly the easier approach.